# Why are there transactions before full synchronization?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

Do you know why there are several transactions before end of full synchronization ?

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot (in french) i think Romain is asking about why there are 70 transactions in the mempool although IBD isn't complete yet.

Comment: Yep, exactly :)

Comment: Is this syncing from scratch or catching up after being offline for some time?

Comment: It was pruned before and then I reloaded the whole blockchain.